# Java fork join algorithm analysis

Tags: java, concurrency, fork-join

I am doing a study (as part of a course requirement) on the new Fork-Join framework in Java 7 and analyze the performance improvement compared to the conventional threading mechanism. What are the kinds of divide and conquer algorithms that are guaranteed to run faster with the new fork join framework. Can you suggest any non-trivial algorithm I can work on to analyze the performance difference.

Comment: And I assume you'll cite this SO question in your references...  don't know if you'll get any reputation credit for that outside link, though. ;-)

Answer (score 4):

You can try N body problem: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/N-body_problem
or
You can try parallel sort

Answer (score 2):

Maybe linear algebra problems would be a good fit: LU or QR decomposition, forward-back substitution, an eigenvalue solution method like Jacobi iteration, etc.

Finite element solution of problems in solid mechanics, heat transfer, and fluid mechanics are significant sources of these kinds of problems.